# Вычисление синуса через ряд Тейлора

Tags: c, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, тригонометрия

Помогите пожалуйста исправить программу. Учитель просит убрать цикл вычитания пи в основной функции. Я не знаю, как написать программу, чтобы получать правильные результаты при любых значениях x после того как убираю цикл вычитания.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double sinus(double x);
int main(void)
{
    double a,x;
    scanf("%le",&x);
    a=x;
    while(fabs(x)>2*(M_PI))
    {
     x=fabs(x)-2*(M_PI);
     }
     if(a>0)
     a=sinus(x);
     else a=(-1)*sinus(x);
    printf("%le",(double)a);
    return 0;}
    
double sinus(double x)
{
  double sum=0, h, eps=1.e-16; int i=2;
 
h=x;
do{
    sum+=h;
    h*=-((x*x)/(i*(i+1)));
    i+=2;}
while( fabs(h)>eps );
return sum;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да , все уже, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я не знаю, как написать программу, чтобы получать правильные
> результаты при любых значениях x после того как убираю цикл вычитания.

Найти остаток от деления на два пи.